# Bash script to restart java application after Jenkins compiling

Tags: java, linux, bash, jenkins

I'm noob in linux! I have my server and installed jenkins. I need to create bash script, which should run application(or will restart if it has already been started) after jenkins compile it. I tried to use screen util in linux, but it's not working for me. I wrote this script:

```
screen -X -S JavaTelegramBot quit
screen -d -m -S JavaTelegramBot
screen -X -S JavaTelegramBot java -jar "path/to/jar"
```

When I tip `screen -ls`, it's empty, so application not working

Comment: may be it's `screen -S JavaTelegramBot -X java ...`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162150/200657

Comment: not working for me

Comment: I used `screen -X -S JavaTelegramBot quit
screen -S JavaTelegramBot
screen -S JavaTelegramBot -X java -jar "path"
`

Comment: I starting script in Jenkins shell... Tried to use nohup, but it's runs application only for few seconds, until jenkins finished building

Comment: This is rather unclear, but it seems that you want to deploy your script from Jenkins and leave it running once the deploy step is done. Using `screen` for that seems rather dubious, but could work if you start the `screen` server from outside Jenkins, and have Jenkins connect to it and start a new job inside it as your deploy action. As you have already observed, Jenkins itself will not leave the build job running indefinitely; doing so would introduce various problems around deciding when a build is done.

Comment: Probably a better design would be to deploy your build as a service, and use `systemd` to restart it when a new version has been installed.